# Store ISO String in mysql column of type DATETIME

Tags: mysql

I have a column of type `DATETIME` in my table.
I want to store there an ISO String, which I need to convert to `DATETIME` in order to store it.

For this, I did some test:
`SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2021-01-07T13:35:34.604Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ');`

But I get as result: `NULL`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: DATETIME stores a date/time in local time. It cannot include time offset.

Answer (score 0):

This did the job:
`SELECT CAST('2021-01-07T13:35:34.604Z' AS DATETIME);`

Comment: Yes, but remove the `Z`. That can be error prone. You are storing an "apple" into a "oranges" box. You can make it fit, yes, but you're going to run into trouble sooner or later.

Comment: @TheImpaler Is there a date type for my iso string? Or I have to use this `DATETIME`

Comment: Your string represents a "world date/time", while `DATETIME` stores local date/times, so there's an incompatibility there that will bite you in the *** at some point. Alternatively, you can use MySQL's `TIMESTAMP` that represents a "world date/time" with some restrictions.

Comment: with `TIMESTAMP` I can store ISO string directly without any casting? @TheImpaler

Comment: No. DATETIME as well as TIMESTAMP store date/times in binary format. If you have a string, you need to convert it to internal format. If you really want to store the string in the exact format then use a VARCHAR column; however, I don't recommend storing date/times in a VARCHAR since it lacks any validation and it will allow you to store any kind of garbage there as well (I''ve seen it, yes I have).